# Deferred components to reduce app bundle size - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, android-app-bundle

Whether the [Deffered component](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/deferred-components) in flutter reduces the app bundle size for play store upload?.

Answer (score 0):

As the document saying

> Flutter has the capability to build apps that can download additional
> Dart code and assets at runtime. This allows apps to reduce install
> apk size and download features and assets when needed by the user.

But the base apk will contain flutter lib. that will be around 9+ MB.

Comment: Then what about hte size of app bundle.